# Most efficient way to track values' position in a list

Tags: javascript, python

```
var list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'];
```

Each time I make an API call and get that list, showing it here as a JavaScript array, I would like to know if any of the items have moved quickly (defined as, say, more than *x* positions) in either direction over the past *n* requests. Each request I get an array with the same elements in a different order.

In other words, if I look at 100 samples of data each taken 1 minute apart and all the elements are moving within the samples at different rate, I would like to detect if any moved within a range of say -n to +n during that timeframe (in this case the timeframe is 100 minutes).

Comment: Please read [What is the X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/102937), and then modify your question accordingly.

Comment: Done, let me know if I can clarify further

Comment: Still a bit vague.  If this is about temporal ordering, why don't you just include a timestamp with each item?

Comment: I'm not the source of the data

Comment: Alright.  Why do you need to know the ordering of the elements?  Is there some way to sort them?

Comment: I want to be able to analyze the history of the requests and determine if one of the elements went from 10th to 2nd position over the last 20 requests for example

Comment: How do you identify a particular element for this analysis?

Comment: I don't need to know the ordering, I need to see the pattern of changes in the ordering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56678/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-fo).

Comment: Your question edit is useful, but you probably meant to write "-x to +x" instead of "-n to +n".

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understood well, you want to detect that in *list*, between,

response #1,

```
['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
```

and response #*n*,

```
['c','b','d','a','g','f','h','e']
```

either of 'a' or 'e' is one value that moved the most? (they both moved by 3 positions)

If so, what you can do is maintain two bijective maps value-to-index, whereby, at response #1,

```
oldMap = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'g': 6, 'h': 7 }
```

and at response #*n*,

```
newMap = { 'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 0, 'd': 2, 'e': 7, 'f': 5, 'g': 4, 'h': 6 }
```

Then, you can just proceed with something along the lines of,

```
var maxMoveValue = null;
var sofar = -1;
for (var value in newMap) {
   var distance = Math.abs(newMap[value] - oldMap[value]);
   var fastMove = (distance > sofar) && (distance >= x);
   maxMoveValue = fastMove ? value : maxMoveValue;
   sofar = fastMove ? distance : sofar;
}
```

where *x* is the threshold you mentioned in the question.

(I left out the initializations of the maps -- from your *list* variable -- and also the update of *oldMap* overwritten by *newMap*, modulo *n* processed responses)

'Hope this helps.

Comment: I like this but the issue isn't which one moved the most between two points in time, but rather between two points in time which one moved most rapidly

Comment: So each comparison is relative to all the other points in time.

Comment: @Fo. well, thanks for clarifying, as that isn't obvious in your question as it is currently phrased. Consider editing it accordingly. Then, I believe you can generalize my answer and maintain n pairs of (oldMap vs newMap) and compute my maxMoveValue for each of those between consecutive API calls, instead of doing it discretely at every multiple of n. Finally, you take the max of those n maxMoveValue(s). Or I am still missing something regarding your "n" parameter. 'Hth.